# Oracle SQL: Minus Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running this individual query in my database software reporting environment and it works well. However I want to be able to take this query and subtract it from the same query with table2.actionid changed to a different value.

Context: 15 and 16 correspond to different user action ids. In this case 16 corresponds to creating a file, while 15 corresponds to deleting a file. In my case, for finding the correct output value, I need the output of this query for user action 16 MINUS the output of this same query for user action 15.
Also ignore the "date >= %1", there is a separate section in my environment where that date can be inputted.

Here are my tables and their respective columns for quick reference:

```
Main Table (id)
Table 1 (defid, id, asubtype)
Table 2 (id, actionid, bsubtype, performerid)
Table 3 (userid)
```

Here is my individual query:

```
SELECT decode(table1.defid,
2189, 'Category1',
3984, 'Category2',
5904, 'Category3',
6238, 'Category4',
6849, 'Category5',
'Unknown') "Category", table1.id "ID Number",
COUNT (table1.defid) as "Running Total"
FROM table1
INNER JOIN
maintable ON maintable.id = table1.id
INNER JOIN
table2 ON table2.id = maintable.id
INNER JOIN 
table3 ON table3.userid = table2.performerid
WHERE table2.actionid = 16
AND auditdate >= %1
AND table2.bsubtype = 0
AND table1.asubtype = -18
GROUP BY table1.defid, table1.id
```

My "Running Total" when table2.actionid = 16 is 2.
My "Running Total" when table2.actionid = 15 is 1.

Two files are created, one is deleted. My output should be all of the files that have been created but not deleted. 
So logically the minus statement output should be 1? Right?

However when I used an Oracle MINUS statement(https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/minus.php), my running total is still 2.

What am I doing wrong? Should I use some sort of subselect instead? 
Have I had too much caffeine? Am I missing something simple? Any input/advice would be super helpful 
:)

This is the minus query:

```
SELECT decode(table1.defid,
2189, 'Category1',
3984, 'Category2',
5904, 'Category3',
6238, 'Category4',
6849, 'Category5',
'Unknown') "Category", table1.id "ID Number",
COUNT (table1.defid) as "Running Total"
FROM table1
INNER JOIN
maintable ON maintable.id = table1.id
INNER JOIN
table2 ON table2.id = maintable.id
INNER JOIN
table3 ON table3.userid = table2.performerid
WHERE table2.actionid = 16
AND auditdate >= %1
AND table2.bsubtype = 0
AND table1.asubtype = -18
GROUP BY table1.defid, table1.id

MINUS

SELECT decode(table1.defid,
2189, 'Category1',
3984, 'Category2',
5904, 'Category3',
6238, 'Category4',
6849, 'Category5',
'Unknown') "Category", table1.id "ID Number",
COUNT (table1.defid) as "Running Total"
FROM table1
INNER JOIN
maintable ON maintable.id = table1.id
INNER JOIN
table2 ON table2.id = maintable.id
INNER JOIN
table3 ON table3.userid = table2.performerid
WHERE table2.actionid = 15
AND auditdate >= %1
AND table2.bsubtype = 0
AND table1.asubtype = -18
GROUP BY table1.defid, table1.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what result you're trying to achieve, but `MINUS` is a *set* operation, i.e. find records in the first result set not present in the second. So if your are looking for the remaining `COUNT`s you need to join these result sets and do subtraction on Running totals instead of `MINUS`

Comment: Thank you! This was super helpful. I will try this out!